# Unable to use object filters for rest api. It doesnt seem to work

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have created a VM on ams01 in my softlayer account and I am trying to filter by datacenter name. Even if I specify the datacenter name as dal05, I get the json for ams01 only.

This is how I have created my URL : @api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectFilter={"datacenter": {"name":{"operation":"ams01"}}}

I have used the blog https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters to experiment on object filters.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: this question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997010/objectfilter-in-softlayer-doesnt-work/42002511#42002511 Regards

Comment: Thank you. That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this request:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,hostname,datacenter]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}}
```

I hope it helps you

Regards