# Softlayer filtering not working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Why is filtering not working as defined in 
[Softlayer API filtering documentation](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters)?

Here is the REST call to the API with filtering:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,datacenter]&objectFilter={"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}
```

And this wont work.
It returns virtual hosts from any datacenter, NOT from dal05 ONLY as expected:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <id>24291415</id>
    <datacenter>
       <id>814994</id>
       <longName>Amsterdam 3</longName>
       <name>ams03</name>
       <statusId>2</statusId>
    </datacenter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>26248749</id>
    <datacenter>
      <id>814994</id>
      <longName>Amsterdam 3</longName>
      <name>ams03</name>
      <statusId>2</statusId>
    </datacenter>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>26248751</id>
    <datacenter>
      <id>814994</id>
      <longName>Amsterdam 3</longName>
      <name>ams03</name>
      <statusId>2</statusId>
    </datacenter>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: The question is a duplicate, already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997010/objectfilter-in-softlayer-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this object filter

```
objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}}
```

Regards

Comment: This answer would benefit everyone greately if you explained ***why?*** SO is a place to help people get to the answer.

Comment: What dazzles me is that such an expensive product has such a poor API, poor examples, and poor documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think this filter is the one which work

objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"datacenter":{"name":{"operation":"dal05"}}}}

Answer (score -1):

Review this link:

- [How to use object filter with softlayer rest api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186972/how-to-use-object-filter-with-softlayer-rest-api)

it will provide a clear idea about how to define object filters